# Hygieia Dashboard with JIRA board

Tags: jira, hygieia

I am trying to configure my project's JIRA board with Hygieia dashboard.

**Problem statement:**

My project on JIRA is created as a "**board**" under another project. I wanna see the stats of that particular board on Hygieia (*instead of whole project*)

is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Hi Fayza, I'm not familiar with Hygieia, however am very experienced with Jira, and so want to help if I can. Could you confirm that my interpretation of your question is correct? 

You have a (non-Jira)"project" which is being accessed in a Jira project through a specific board, and you would like those issues to be viewed within Hygieia?

Comment: Hi @TomGionfriddo
thanks. so basically, there's some random "JIRA project" (of the organization) and my project is created as a board under that project (along with many other boards - different projects).

i want the issues of my board ONLY to be viewed in Hygieia

Comment: Hmmm, are you able to use JQL to filter which Jira issues are imported to import into Hygieia? If so, you could write a simple JQL query to filter only the issues from your project